# XML Explicit - not able to get heirarchy

Tags: sql, xml

I have a following table and its contents are as follows:

```
productType product comments    val
LL          P1       T1       5801309.42
LL          P2       T2       336320.76
LL          P2       T2       311734.56
LL          P2       T2       136381.42
LL          P2       T2       91023.48
```

I use following query using XML Explicit  with 3 levels  of heirarchy
Level1-->Level2-->Level3

```
SELECT distinct 1    as Tag,  
       NULL as Parent,  
       productType as [Level1!1!productType],  
       NULL       as [Level2!2!product]    ,
       NULL       as [Level3!3!comments!ELEMENT]   ,
       NULL       as [Level3!3!val!ELEMENT]
FROM   #t1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT distinct 2 as Tag,  
       1 as Parent,  
       productType,  
       product ,
        NULL,
        NULL 
FROM   #t1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT distinct 3 as Tag,  
       2 as Parent,  
       productType,  
       product ,
        comments,val 
FROM   #t1 
ORDER BY 1,2,3,4
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

I get following XML output. Level 2 Product type P1 does not get Level 3 under it

```
<Level1 productType="LL">
  <Level2 product="P1" />
  <Level2 product="P2">
    <Level3>
      <comments>T1</comments>
      <val>5801309.42</val>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>91023.48</val>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>136381.42</val>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>311734.56</val>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>336320.76</val>
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
</Level1>
```

But desired output is

```
<Level1 productType="LL">
  <Level2 product="P1" >
    <Level3>
        <comments>T1</comments>
        <val>5801309.42</val>
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
  <Level2 product="P2">
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>91023.48</val>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>136381.42</val>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>311734.56</val>
    </Level3>
    <Level3>
      <comments>T2</comments>
      <val>336320.76</val>
    </Level3>
  </Level2>
</Level1>
```

Is there anything in the code - with 3 union statements missing directive to relate Lelvel3 to Level 2

---- Query after fixing  order by -------

```
SELECT distinct 1    as Tag,  
       NULL as Parent,  
       productType as [Level1!1!productType],  
       NULL       as [Level2!2!product]    ,
       NULL       as [Level3!3!comments!ELEMENT]   ,
       NULL       as [Level3!3!val!ELEMENT]
FROM   #t1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT distinct 2 as Tag,  
       1 as Parent,  
       productType,  
       product ,
        NULL,
        NULL 
FROM   #t1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT distinct 3 as Tag,  
       2 as Parent,  
       productType,  
       product ,
        comments,val 
FROM   #t1 
ORDER BY  4,3,2,1
FOR XML EXPLICIT;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order of the rows matters.
Reference  [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-explicit-mode-with-for-xml?view=sql-server-2017#universal-table-row-ordering)
Output of your query is:

```
TAG PARENT  LEVEL1  LEVEL2  LEVEL3  LEVEL3ELEMENT
1   (null)  LL      (null)  (null)  (null)
2   1       LL      P1      (null)  (null)
2   1       LL      P2      (null)  (null)
3   2       LL      P1      T1      5801309
3   2       LL      P2      T2      136381
3   2       LL      P2      T2      311735
3   2       LL      P2      T2      336321
3   2       LL      P2      T2      91023
```

For your result, it requires:

```
TAG PARENT  LEVEL1  LEVEL2  LEVEL3  LEVEL3ELEMENT
1   (null)  LL      (null)  (null)  (null)
2   1       LL      P1      (null)  (null)
3   2       LL      P1      T1      5801309
2   1       LL      P2      (null)  (null)
3   2       LL      P2      T2      136381
3   2       LL      P2      T2      311735
3   2       LL      P2      T2      336321
3   2       LL      P2      T2      91023
```

Row number 3 and 4 should be swapped for element `T1` to come under element `P1`

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT distinct 1    as Tag,  
       NULL as Parent,  
       productType as Level1,  
       NULL       as Level2    ,
       NULL       as Level3   ,
       NULL       as Level3ELEMENT
FROM   t1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT distinct 2 as Tag,  
       1 as Parent,  
       productType,  
       product ,
        NULL,
        NULL 
FROM   t1  
UNION ALL  
SELECT distinct 3 as Tag,  
       2 as Parent,  
       productType,  
       product ,
        comments,val 
FROM   t1 
) asd
order by 
CASE WHEN Level1 is null THEN '1'
ELSE Level1 End,
CASE WHEN Level2 is null THEN '1'
ELSE Level2 End,
CASE WHEN Level3 is null THEN '1'
ELSE Level3 End
```